# Creating an array from a text file read from a URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am reading a text file from a URL and want to parse the contents of the file into an array.  Below is a snippet of the code I am using.  I want to be able to place each line of the text into the next row of the array.  Is there a way to identify the carriage return/line feed during or after the text has been retrieved?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kTextURL];
textView.text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding                        error:nil];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When separating by newline characters it's best to use the following procedure:

```
NSCharacterSet *newlines = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
NSArray *lineComponents = [textFile componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:newlines];
```

This ensures that you get lines separated by either CR, CR+LF, or NEL.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that. Nice! +1

Comment: This is good, but it will interpret CRLF as two different line endings, so you'll be left with an empty element in the array for each CRLF.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NSString`'s [`-componentsSeparatedByString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) method, which will return to you an `NSArray`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kTextURL];
NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
textView.text = response;
NSArray *lines = [response componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

//iterate through the lines...
for(NSString *line in lines) {
   //do something with line...
}
```

Comment: If it's a line feed/carriage return, you can try componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"

Comment: 'componentSeparatedByCharactersInSet' actually created an index with the '\r\n'.  So I replaced it with the following change:

Comment: NSArray *lines = [response componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];